# Sort a listbox with click on a button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need some help with sorting a listbox in my form.

I have a listbox (`LstPlanung`) that lists all entries of a table.

```
HID        SID        DATUM            ZEIT

AAA        AA         20.02.2017       15:00
BBB        BB         16.02.2017       17:00
...        ..         ..........       .....
```

Is there a chance to sort the listbox with a button by "`DATUM`" ?

Answer (score 2):

Listbox columns are text only, so even if the listbox would have in-built sorting, it wouldn't work with `dd.mm.yyyy` dates.

To sort correctly by dates (or numbers), the sorting must be done in the `RowSource` property.

I suggest to use the following code by John Spencer to sort by any column via right-click.
It's super-useful and I use it in many listboxes.

Source: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1953978

```
Public Sub sSortListBox(anyListbox As Control, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single)
'Purpose: Sort list box by column when column is right-clicked
'Author: Copyright by John Spencer
'Version Date: 04-14-2004
'Limitations:
' No Horizontal scroll bar in listbox
' RowSource must be query
' Uses DAO code; not tested with ADP
'Permission to use in applications is granted to all
'with the understanding that credit is given to the author.
'No warrantee or guaranty is given - use at your own risk.
'
'Code to sort list in ascending/descending order
'depending on which column is right-clicked
'and whether shift key is pressed.
'Uses the SQL syntax of specifying a column number as the sort column -
' SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY N
'- where N is integer reflecting the position of a field in SELECT clause.
'Install call to this code in the Mouse Down event of a listbox.
'Example -
' sSortListBox Me.SomeListbox, Button, Shift, X
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'In the listbox's Mouse Up event add code to cancel the Mouse up event.
' If Button = acRightButton Then DoCmd.CancelEvent
'That line will stop any popup menu from appearing.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim vGetWidths As Variant
    Dim vArWidths() As Variant
    Dim iColCount As Integer, iColNumber As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iColWidthSum As Integer
    Dim iUndefined As Integer
    Dim iDefaultWidth As Integer
    Dim strOrderBy As String
    Dim xStr As Long
    Const strListSeparator As String = ";" 'list Separator

On Error GoTo ERROR_sSortListBox

    If Button <> acRightButton Then
        'only sort based on right button being clicked

    ElseIf anyListbox.RowSourceType <> "table/query" Then
        'only sort listbox based on queries
        MsgBox "List box must use a query as it's row source"

    ElseIf Len(anyListbox.RowSource) = 0 Then
        'Nothing there, so ignore the click

    ElseIf Not (InStr(1, Trim(anyListbox.RowSource), "Select", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
            Or InStr(1, Trim(anyListbox.RowSource), "Parameters", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
        'If rowsource does not start with SELECT or PARAMETERS then
        'assume it is a table not a query
        MsgBox "List box must use a query as its row source"

    ElseIf anyListbox.columnCount > DBEngine(0)(0).CreateQueryDef("", anyListbox.RowSource).Fields.Count Then
        'Column count must be correctly set, otherwise this routine
        'could cause errors. Column count set less than actual field count
        'will cause subscript errors. Column count set higher than actual
        'field count can cause listbox to display nothing if "Extra" column
        'is clicked.
        MsgBox "List box column count does not match query field count!"

    Else 'passed the error checks

    With anyListbox
        iColCount = .columnCount
        ReDim vArWidths(iColCount - 1, 0 To 1)

        'Parse the column widths into an array.
        vGetWidths = Split(.ColumnWidths, strListSeparator, -1, vbTextCompare)

        'Assign values to array that holds length and running sum of length
        For i = 0 To UBound(vGetWidths)
            iColWidthSum = iColWidthSum + Val(vGetWidths(i))
            vArWidths(i, 1) = iColWidthSum
            vArWidths(i, 0) = vGetWidths(i)
        Next i

        'Adjust any colwidths that are unspecified:
        'The minimum is the larger of 1440
        'or the remaining available width of the list box
        'divided by number of columns with unspecified lengths.
        For i = 0 To iColCount - 1
            If Len(vArWidths(i, 0) & vbNullString) = 0 Then
                iUndefined = iUndefined + 1
            End If
        Next i

        If iUndefined <> 0 Then
            iDefaultWidth = (.Width - iColWidthSum) / iUndefined
        End If

        If iDefaultWidth > 0 And iDefaultWidth < 1440 Then
            MsgBox "Sorry! Can't process listboxes with horizontal scrollbars!"
            Exit Sub 'Horizontal scroll bar present
        Else
            'recalculate widths and running sum of column widths
            iColWidthSum = 0
            For i = 0 To iColCount - 1
                If Len(vArWidths(i, 0) & vbNullString) = 0 Then
                    vArWidths(i, 0) = iDefaultWidth
                End If
                iColWidthSum = iColWidthSum + Val(vArWidths(i, 0))
                vArWidths(i, 1) = iColWidthSum
            Next i
        End If

        'Set right edge of last column equal to width of listbox
        vArWidths(iColCount - 1, 1) = .Width

        'Determine which column was clicked
        For i = 0 To iColCount - 1
            If X <= vArWidths(i, 1) Then
                iColNumber = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        iColNumber = iColNumber + 1 'adjust since i is 0 to n-1

        'rebuild sql statement
        If iColNumber > 0 And iColNumber <= iColCount Then
            strSQL = Trim(.RowSource)

            If right(strSQL, 1) = ";" Then strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 1)

            xStr = InStr(1, strSQL, "Order by", vbTextCompare)
            If xStr > 0 Then
                strOrderBy = Trim(Mid(strSQL, xStr + Len("Order by")))
                strSQL = Trim(Left(strSQL, xStr - 1))
            End If

            'Build the appropriate ORDER BY clause
            If Shift = acShiftMask Then
                'If shift key is down force sort to desc on selected column
                strOrderBy = " Order By " & iColNumber & " Desc"

            ElseIf Len(strOrderBy) = 0 Then
                'If no prior sort then sort this column ascending
                strOrderBy = " Order by " & iColNumber & " Asc"

            ElseIf InStr(1, strOrderBy, iColNumber & " Asc", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                'If already sorted asc on this column then sort descending
                strOrderBy = " Order By " & iColNumber & " Desc"

            ElseIf InStr(1, strOrderBy, iColNumber & " Desc", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                'If already sorted desc on this column then sort Ascending
                strOrderBy = " Order By " & iColNumber & " Asc"

            Else
                strOrderBy = " Order by " & iColNumber & " Asc"
            End If

            strSQL = strSQL & strOrderBy
            Debug.Print strSQL
            .RowSource = strSQL

        End If 'Rebuild SQL if col number is in range 1 to number of columns
    End With 'current list
    End If 'Passed error checks

EXIT_sSortListBox:
    Exit Sub

ERROR_sSortListBox:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9 'Subscript out of range
            MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & _
            vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Check column count property of list box.", vbInformation, "ERROR: sSortListBox"

        Case Else 'unexpected error
            MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbInformation, "ERROR: sSortListBox"
    End Select

    Resume EXIT_sSortListBox
End Sub
```

and in the form:

```
Private Sub myList_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Call sSortListBox(Me.myList, Button, Shift, X)
End Sub

Private Sub myList_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = acRightButton Then DoCmd.CancelEvent
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use VBA to manage the `RowSource` of `LstPlanung`.

In the simplest scenario where `LstPlanung` does not already have an `ORDER BY`, you could just use:

```
Me.LstPlanung.RowSource=Me.LstPlanung.RowSource & " ORDER BY Datum"
Me.LstPlanung.Requery
```

If it already has an `ORDER BY` then you will have to re-create the `RowSource` (probably by copy paste the existing one in your code and replacing whatever is in the `ORDER BY` part with 'Datum').

Comment: Note: `Listbox.Requery` isn't needed after changing its `.RowSource`.