# How can I find out which column of multicolumn listbox a user clicks

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form with a textbox with 8 columns. In column 0 to 5 I show things like dates and names, they are not very relevant. Column6 shows the first 30 characters of a remark that can contain up to 500 characters. Column 7 shows name and pathname of an attachment.

Now I want to show the full remark text in a pop up window when one clicks column 6, but when one clicks column 7 I want to launch the application (Word/Excel/Abobe/etc.) that corresponds with the attachment and show content of that attachment.

Therefore I need to know in which column the mouseclick happens. I cannot find any property that indicates the column of the mouse position.

I tried using cursor position (X and Y) but that is affected by the resolution.

Is there an other way?

Comment: You mean listbox instead of textbox as referenced in your first sentence? Columns are not clicked, rows are clicked. Doesn't matter where the cursor is positioned. You should rethink your design.

Comment: Rather than use a listbox, look at using a continuous form.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant listbox indeed. But depending on which colom in the row is clicked I want the program to react differently.

Comment: This function uses X to determine which column was clicked, and works on different resolutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42272773/3820271

Answer (score 0):

It just an idea. never try it myself.

Use mouse position/coordinates using GetCursorPos API.
You have to make sure the form position always static (does not move) and you set the vertical ranges of your columns and use its value to determines which column range is clicked.